# emacs org-odt-export-as-odf-and-open odt outside emacs

Tags: emacs, export, external, org-mode, odt

The intuitive use for the orgmode option to export and view and odt file should be to view it in an libre/open office. However, I've so far had no luck in getting it to work; it always opens as a compressed archive in emacs. By inserting into my .emacs

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.odt\\'" . "xdg-open %s"))
```

I open them properly when accessing links to files in org files, but it doesn't seem to effect the export-and-view option. I've looked into changing `org-odt-export-as-odf-and-open` but have not been able to see it make a difference. Any help would be appreciated. Once again, I want `org-odt-export-as-odf-and-open` to open the odf with xdg-open or libreoffice, not Emacs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** A more graceful solution was given on the org-mode list that doesn't require editing any of your packaged org files. Simply add the following to your .emacs to rebind what 'system is doing:

```lisp
(setcdr (assq 'system org-file-apps-defaults-gnu ) "xdg-open %s")
```

<del>There's an error in the current version of the code. It can be fixed by editing line 97 of ox-odt.el:

:menu-entry
      '(?o "Export to ODT"
           ((?o "As ODT file" org-odt-export-to-odt)
        (?O "As ODT file and open"
            (lambda (a s v b)
              (if a (org-odt-export-to-odt t s v)
            (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt nil s v) 'system))))))

by removing that last `'system`, so you have:


:menu-entry
      '(?o "Export to ODT"
           ((?o "As ODT file" org-odt-export-to-odt)
        (?O "As ODT file and open"
            (lambda (a s v b)
              (if a (org-odt-export-to-odt t s v)
            (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt nil s v) ))))))

You may also need to edit the ox-odt.elc equivalently if you are using a compiled version.</del>

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I got `setcdr: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-file-apps-defaults-gnu`. Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

The [function you are calling](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ox-odt.el?id=release_8.2.7#n4163) is for exporting OpenDocument *formulas* (`.odf` files), not OpenDocument text documents (`.odt` files):

> ```
> Export LaTeX fragment as OpenDocument formula and immediately open it.
> Use `org-odt-export-as-odf' to read LaTeX fragment and OpenDocument
> formula file.
> ```

Since the exported file doesn't have a `.odt` extension your addition to `org-file-apps` doesn't affect it.

I don't see any built-in function to export Org mode documents to LibreOffice Writer files and open them, but it is trivial to write:

```lisp
(defun my-org-export-to-odt-and-open ()
  (interactive)
  (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt)))
```

Comment: Curious. <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> does say "Export to ODT->As ODT file and open" so must be calling the wrong thing. But the output file is certainly an ODT file (it resides in the directory).

Comment: Why does your code work but not [the included code](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ox-odt.el?id=release_8.2.7#n97)?

Comment: You're right that `C-c C-e o O` is described as exporting "As ODT file and open". I'm not sure what function that runs (the Org export dispatcher is beyond me). I'm almost positive that it does *not* run `org-odt-export-as-odf-and-open`, as that function is definitely for OpenDocument formulas. But that binding *does* work, launching LibreOffice, on my machine.

Comment: Ah, you've found it! I'm not sure why the built-in code doesn't work on your machine. In fact, it works just fine on mine, even without having to modify `org-file-apps`. What's your `org-version`?

Comment: Org-mode version 8.2.6 (8.2.6-73-g88f262-elpa

Comment: We've got very nearly the same Org as well... Mine's `Org-mode version 8.2.6 (release_8.2.6-1 @ /usr/share/emacs/24.4.50/lisp/org/)`. If you browse the code on your machine (e.g. using `M-x find-library RET ox-odt RET`, then find the call to `org-export-define-backend`), does that version look correct?

Comment: Yes; that's actually how I found it on the webpage; by grepping it locally first.

Comment: Then I'm at a loss. Good luck tracking this down!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solution of WorldsEndless but it doesn't work for me, instead I use this variation

```
(setcdr (assq 'system org-file-apps-defaults-gnu ) '(call-process "xdg-open" nil 0 nil file))
```