# emacs org-mode exports odt file but opens with PDF viewer

Tags: emacs, org-mode, odt, okular

For some reason org-mode correctly exports to an ODT file but opens it with the default PDF viewer (okular) instead of libreoffice. I have tried all the solutions mentioned in a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434854/emacs-org-odt-export-as-odf-and-open-odt-outside-emacs) without any luck. For reference I am copying below the relevant sections of my init file. My emacs is 27.0.50 and my org-mode is 9.1.13.

```
;; Enable export in ODT format
(eval-after-load "org" '(require 'ox-odt nil t)) ; enable odt backend
;; Open ODT files with libre office
(defun my-org-export-to-odt-and-open ()
  (interactive)
  (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt)))
```

and in my custom-set-variables I have

```
 '(org-file-apps
   '((auto-mode . emacs)
     ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
     ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
     ("\\.odt\\'" . "libreoffice %s") 
     ("\\.pdf\\'" . "okular %s")))
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

This is the output value of org-file-apps

```
Value:
((auto-mode . emacs)
 ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
 ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
 ("\\.odt\\'" . "libreoffice %s")
 ("\\.pdf\\'" . "okular %s"))
Original value was 
((auto-mode . emacs)
 ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
 ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
 ("\\.pdf\\'" . default))
```

and this is one output of edebug on `org-open-file` when I tried to export a NOTES.org file.

```
Debugger entered--returning value: nil
  string-match("\\$\\(?:\\(?1:[[:alnum:]_]+\\)\\|{\\(?1:[^{}]+\\)}\\|\\$\\)" "/home/andre/org/NOTES.odt" 0)
* substitute-env-vars("/home/andre/org/NOTES.odt" t)
* substitute-env-in-file-name("/home/andre/org/NOTES.odt")
* substitute-in-file-name("/home/andre/org/NOTES.odt")
* #f(compiled-function (path &optional in-emacs line search) "Open the file at PATH.\nFirst, this expands any special file name abbreviations.  Then the\nconfiguration variable `org-file-apps' is checked if it contains an\nentry for this file type, and if yes, the corresponding command is launched.\n\nIf no application is found, Emacs simply visits the file.\n\nWith optional prefix argument IN-EMACS, Emacs will visit the file.\nWith a double \\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument] prefix arg, Org tries to avoid opening in Emacs\nand to use an external application to visit the file.\n\nOptional LINE specifies a line to go to, optional SEARCH a string\nto search for.  If LINE or SEARCH is given, the file will be\nopened in Emacs, unless an entry from org-file-apps that makes\nuse of groups in a regexp matches.\n\nIf you want to change the way frames are used when following a\nlink, please customize `org-link-frame-setup'.\n\nIf the file does not exist, an error is thrown." #<bytecode 0x1524219>)("NOTES.odt" system)
* apply(#f(compiled-function (path &optional in-emacs line search) "Open the file at PATH.\nFirst, this expands any special file name abbreviations.  Then the\nconfiguration variable `org-file-apps' is checked if it contains an\nentry for this file type, and if yes, the corresponding command is launched.\n\nIf no application is found, Emacs simply visits the file.\n\nWith optional prefix argument IN-EMACS, Emacs will visit the file.\nWith a double \\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument] prefix arg, Org tries to avoid opening in Emacs\nand to use an external application to visit the file.\n\nOptional LINE specifies a line to go to, optional SEARCH a string\nto search for.  If LINE or SEARCH is given, the file will be\nopened in Emacs, unless an entry from org-file-apps that makes\nuse of groups in a regexp matches.\n\nIf you want to change the way frames are used when following a\nlink, please customize `org-link-frame-setup'.\n\nIf the file does not exist, an error is thrown." #<bytecode 0x1524219>) ("NOTES.odt" system))
* org-open-file("NOTES.odt" system)
  (if a (org-odt-export-to-odt t s v) (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt nil s v) 'system))
  (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-odt-export-to-odt t s v) (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt nil s v) 'system)))(nil t nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

I kept moving forward until the point shown below. It looks as if the file was matched as `\\.mm\\`?

```
Debugger entered--returning value: (10578 10582)
  match-data()
* regexp-opt-depth("\\.mm\\'")
* org-file-apps-entry-match-against-dlink-p(("\\.mm\\'" . default))
* cl-remove(nil ((auto-mode . emacs) ("\\.mm\\'" . default) ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default) ("\\.odt\\'" . "libreoffice %s") ("\\.pdf\\'" . "okular %s") (remote . emacs) (system . mailcap) (t . mailcap)) :if org-file-apps-entry-match-against-dlink-p)
* apply(cl-remove nil ((auto-mode . emacs) ("\\.mm\\'" . default) ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default) ("\\.odt\\'" . "libreoffice %s") ("\\.pdf\\'" . "okular %s") (remote . emacs) (system . mailcap) (t . mailcap)) :if org-file-apps-entry-match-against-dlink-p nil)
* cl-remove-if(org-file-apps-entry-match-against-dlink-p ((auto-mode . emacs) ("\\.mm\\'" . default) ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default) ("\\.odt\\'" . "libreoffice %s") ("\\.pdf\\'" . "okular %s") (remote . emacs) (system . mailcap) (t . mailcap)))
* #f(compiled-function (path &optional in-emacs line search) "Open the file at PATH.\nFirst, this expands any special file name abbreviations.  Then the\nconfiguration variable `org-file-apps' is checked if it contains an\nentry for this file type, and if yes, the corresponding command is launched.\n\nIf no application is found, Emacs simply visits the file.\n\nWith optional prefix argument IN-EMACS, Emacs will visit the file.\nWith a double \\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument] prefix arg, Org tries to avoid opening in Emacs\nand to use an external application to visit the file.\n\nOptional LINE specifies a line to go to, optional SEARCH a string\nto search for.  If LINE or SEARCH is given, the file will be\nopened in Emacs, unless an entry from org-file-apps that makes\nuse of groups in a regexp matches.\n\nIf you want to change the way frames are used when following a\nlink, please customize `org-link-frame-setup'.\n\nIf the file does not exist, an error is thrown." #<bytecode 0x1524219>)("NOTES.odt" system)
* apply(#f(compiled-function (path &optional in-emacs line search) "Open the file at PATH.\nFirst, this expands any special file name abbreviations.  Then the\nconfiguration variable `org-file-apps' is checked if it contains an\nentry for this file type, and if yes, the corresponding command is launched.\n\nIf no application is found, Emacs simply visits the file.\n\nWith optional prefix argument IN-EMACS, Emacs will visit the file.\nWith a double \\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument] prefix arg, Org tries to avoid opening in Emacs\nand to use an external application to visit the file.\n\nOptional LINE specifies a line to go to, optional SEARCH a string\nto search for.  If LINE or SEARCH is given, the file will be\nopened in Emacs, unless an entry from org-file-apps that makes\nuse of groups in a regexp matches.\n\nIf you want to change the way frames are used when following a\nlink, please customize `org-link-frame-setup'.\n\nIf the file does not exist, an error is thrown." #<bytecode 0x1524219>) ("NOTES.odt" system))
* org-open-file("NOTES.odt" system)
  (if a (org-odt-export-to-odt t s v) (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt nil s v) 'system))
  (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-odt-export-to-odt t s v) (org-open-file (org-odt-export-to-odt nil s v) 'system)))(nil t nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

Actually, I kept moving forward and there was no match against any of the options available in org-file-apps.

Comment: FIrst make sure that you are *setting* `org-file-apps` in your running emacs: what does `C-h v org-file-apps RET` say? If it does *not* include the odt setting, your custom file is not being used. If it does include the odt setting, I would use [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/edebug.html) on `org-open-file` to see where things go awry.

Comment: @NickD Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your help. I will put the output of the `org-file-apps` and the `org-open-file` above. Since I am not a very experienced lisp user I might need some help at interpreting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging I came across these posts: [post1](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/8doy5e/export_and_open_to_odt_fails_to_open_with_lowriter/) [post2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646631/emacs-doesnot-work-with-xdg-open/824123#824123)
from which the following solution emerged:

```
;; Enable export in ODT format
(setcdr (assq 'system org-file-apps-defaults-gnu ) "xdg-open %s")
(setq process-connection-type nil)
```

without anything configured on the org-file-apps.